# Entry Point Not Found Exception

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I'm trying to use a C++ unmanaged dll in a C# project and I'm getting an error when trying to call a function that says that entry point cannot be found.

```
public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr testIntPtr = aaeonAPIOpen(0);            
        Console.WriteLine(testIntPtr.ToString());
    }

    [DllImport("aonAPI.dll")]
    public static extern unsafe IntPtr aaeonAPIOpen(uint reserved);
}
```

Here is the dumpbin for the function:

```
5    4 00001020 ?aaeonAPIOpen@@YAPAXK@Z
```

I changed the dll import to `[DllImport("aonAPI.dll", EntryPoint="?aaeonAPIOpen")]` and `[DllImport("aonAPI.dll", EntryPoint="_aaeonAPIOpen")]` and no luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the undname.exe utility, that symbol demangles to

```
 void * __cdecl aaeonAPIOpen(unsigned long)
```

Which makes the proper declaration:

```
    [DllImport("aonAPI.dll", EntryPoint="?aaeonAPIOpen@@YAPAXK@Z", 
        ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr aaeonAPIOpen(uint reserved);
```

Comment: +1, didn't realize you could do that.  How safe is this approach?  Does the mangled name change from build to build or is it consistent across builds of the same code?

Comment: @Jared: the mangling is purely based on the declaration of the C++ function.  Which is why undname.exe can work.  It's stable as long as the declaration doesn't change.  This makes it *safer* than an extern "C" declaration.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the function you're trying to call is compiled as a C++ function and hence has it's name mangled.  PInvoke does not support mangled name.  You need to add an extern "C" block around the function definition to prevent name mangling

```
extern "C" {
  void* aaeonAPIOpen(uint reserved);
}
```