# Import C++ DLL with pointer into C#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I know that there are many solutions for my problem. I have tried them all; however, I still get error.

These are original functions from DLL 'KeygenLibrary.dll' :

```
bool dfcDecodeMachineID(char* sEncodeMachineID, int iInLen, char* sMachineID, int& iOutLen);

bool dfcCreateLicense(char* sMachineID, int iLen, char* sLicenseFilePath);
```

To import this DLL, I have tried:

Way 1:

```
unsafe public class ImportDLL
{
    [DllImport("KeygenLibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "dfcDecodeMachineID")]
    unsafe public static extern bool dfcDecodeMachineID(char* sEncodeMachineID, int iInLen, char* sMachineID, ref int iOutLen);

    [DllImport("KeygenLibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "dfcCreateLicense")]
    unsafe public static extern bool dfcCreateLicense(char* sMachineID, int iLen, char* sLicenseFilePath);
}
```

Way 2:

```
public class ImportDLL
{
    [DllImport("KeygenLibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "dfcDecodeMachineID")]
    public static extern bool dfcDecodeMachineID([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string sEncodeMachineID, int iInLen, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string sMachineID, ref int iOutLen);


    [DllImport("KeygenLibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "dfcCreateLicense")]
    public static extern bool dfcCreateLicense([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string sMachineID, int iLen, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string sLicenseFilePath);
}
```

However, both above ways give me error:

Unable to find an entry point named 'function name' in DLL 'KeygenLibrary.dll'.

How can I fix my problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll want to have an `extern "C"` to prevent name mangling, as well as `__declspec(dllexport)`. And if those `char *`s are being modified, you'll have to use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I will add extern "c" to my C# code or C++? I cant edit C++ file.

Comment: SUGGESTION: run "dumpbin" on your .dll.  If the names look more like this: `?Close@CHIDDevice@@QAEEXZ` (instead of `Close`), then you know the problem is C++ name mangling.

Comment: C++, and that's unfortunate because now you need to know the calling convention and/or the mangled name (you can use one to figure out the other). Perhaps a symbol table. Disclaimer: I've never tried without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUGGESTION:

1) Run "dumpbin" on your .dll to confirm the problem is indeed name mangling.

2) If so, try the suggestion in this link:

[Entry Point Not Found Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515270/entry-point-not-found-exception/3515377#3515377)

a) Use [undname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699.aspx) to get the undecorated name

b) Set EntryPointy == the mangled name

c) Set CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl

d) Use the unmangled name and signature for your C# method signature

See also this link:

> http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/428504-c-program-calling-c-dll
>
> Laurent.... You can call the function using the mangled name as in:
>
> To call a function using its fully decorated name
>   `"?fnWin32Test2@@YAJXZ"` as
>
> "Win32Test2" you can specify the static entry point as
>   `"?fnWin32Test2@@YAJXY":`
>
> ```
> [DllImport("Win32Test.dll", EntryPoint= "?fnWin32Test2@@YAJXZ")]
> public static extern int fnWin32Test2();
> ```
>
> And call it as:
>
> `System.Console.WriteLine(fnWin32Test2());`
>
> To look at the undecorated name use the undname tool as in:
>
> ```
> `undname ?fnWin32Test@@3HA`
> ```
>
> This converts the decorated name to "long fnWin32Test".
>
> Regards, Jeff

Comment: Thank you very much. I have spent a whole day to find this problem.