# C++ dll throws EntryPointNotFoundException in C# code

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use some external C++ code in my C# (Unity) project. I decided to create a .dll file. 
My problem is when I try to run my program, it throws an exception at calling dll's function. 
My code looks something like this:

```
// Something.h

#ifndef SOMETHING_H
#define SOMETHING_H

extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall f(int a, const char** b, char* c);

#endif
```

```
// Something.cpp

int f(int a, const char** b, const char* c) {
// some stuff
}
```

```
// Something.cs

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Something
{
    [DllImport("Something.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int f(
        int a,
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string[] b,
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string c
    );
}
```

I'm think that I'm doing something nasty with that `string[] -> const char**` conversion but i'm not sure because it's my first try with mixing languages by **.dll** or **.so**.

Here is the part of exception thrown:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: f
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Something.f(int,string[],string)
```

Thanks for any attention.

Best Regards,

Xavrax

Comment: may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515270/entry-point-not-found-exception

Comment: @KevinKouketsu Thank you so much. Dumpbin was exactly what I needed. There were some linking troubles that i didn't know that could apear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `f` declaration doesn't match your `f` implementation so they are separate functions. Change the type of `c` so that it is the same in both declaration and implementation.

You can help avoid this problem by putting `extern "C"` on both the declaration and implementation which will result in a compiler error if the arguments don't match:

```
extern "C"  int f(int a, const char** b, const char* c) {
```

results in:

```
error C2733: 'f': second C linkage of overloaded function not allowed
note: see declaration of 'f'
```

Note: this wont help if there is a typo in the function name though.